# Error CS0136 in Azure DevOps but not local

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When using linq in an EF query, i get a strange result in compiling. Below you find a piece of code where i reuse the variable t in the lambda function. On my local PC, visual studio does not generate an error and compiles and runs correctly. But when the piece of code is compiled by an azure devops pipeline, error CS0136 is generated:

> A local or parameter named 't' cannot be declared in this scope
>   because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a
>   local or parameter

I use VS2019 on my local machine and VS2019 on the agent server for devops (Note: this is a self-hosted agent!)

```
using(Context db = new Context())
 {


 var orderInformation = db
   .Orders
   .Where(t => t.Enabled)
   .Select(t =>  => new
   {
     t.ID,
     t.Name,
     ExtraInfo= t
       .Information
       .Where(t => t.OrderDate >= startDate && t.OrderDate <= endDate)
    })
   .ToList()
}
```

The correct syntax should be:

```
using(Context db = new Context())
 {


 var orderInformation = db
   .Orders
   .Where(t => t.Enabled)
   .Select(t =>  => new
   {
     t.ID,
     t.Name,
     ExtraInfo= t
       .Information
       .Where(x => x.OrderDate >= startDate && x.OrderDate <= endDate)
    })
   .ToList()
}
```

The difference is the lambda parameter in the inner where. My local visual studio accepts both examples, but the visual studio on our azure agents throws a compile error on the first

Comment: Can you share all the code?

Comment: It has to be the code is different, or compiler, or machine state

Comment: Shoudnot the syntax be like `Select(  => ).Where(t => t.OrderDate >= startDate && t.OrderDate <= endDate)`

Comment: @SOosterwaal Any updates for this case?

Comment: No update yet, we still have the problem. A full example of the code has been added to the original post

Comment: Same problem here with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.4.1. Is there a way to turn on error/warning  message on development time?

Comment: Very likely a language version difference in the two environments. Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60388747/why-is-c-sharp-cs0136-error-not-reported-when-compiled-with-langversionlatest?noredirect=1&lq=1)