# Why is C# CS0136 error not reported when compiled with /langversion:latest

Tags: c#, lambda, scope, msbuild, roslyn

The code below compiles fine in Debug but failed with a CS0136(A local or parameter named 'x' cannot be decaled..) error in Release. Anybody has any idea why the error is not reported in Debug build?

```
public void test()
{
    Action<int> a = x => x++;
    int x = 0;
}
```

Target framework 4.6.1
VS version: 16.4.3 and 16.4.5
MSBuildVersion: 16.4.0
MSBuildRuntimeVersion = 4.0.30319

After some investigation, I was able to trace the error to this configuration difference between debug and release build

Debug build has this line in config, but release build does not have.

```
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
```

and this problem can be reproduced with the following two command

```
csc.exe /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll" /langversion:7.3 Program.cs"
csc.exe /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll" /langversion:latest Program.cs"
```

Comment: you have 2 variables with the same name. change the second variable name to int y = 0; or anything

Comment: @Baahubali I modified my question. I was asking why is the error NOT reported in debug

Comment: @XiaoguoGe Which version of .NET are you using, is it .NET Core or .NET Framework? I can't reproduce it, observe only _CS0219_ warning in .NET Core. .NET Framework shows _CS0136_ error for debug and release

Comment: i can't reproduce it either. my code does not compile

Comment: @Pavel Anikhoushi It is a .net framework project targeting 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some partial answers:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639477/why-is-shadowing-of-locals-in-c-sharp-8-allowed) asked about the same thing. A comment from @Hans Passant referenced [This Document](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-01-16.md) which indicates there is a relaxation of the scoping rule for lambdas.

This can explain why /langversion:latest and /langversion:7.3 behave differently

For a .net 4.6.1 project though, I would assume /langversion:latest should result in at most C# 7.3. But apparently it is not the case or maybe there is something else going on here. Hope somebody can shed more light on this.

Comment: "For a .net 4.6.1 project though, I would assume /langversion:latest should result in at most C# 7.3." - nope, it can still handle *most* C# 8 features.

Comment: @JonSkeet Looks like I misunderstood default language version provided on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). Apparently /langversion:latest does not mean default. It overwrites default and uses the C# 8.0 when it is available.

Comment: Yes, exactly - default is only what it says it is: the default if you don't specify anything else.